# mail is not sending from azure portal webapp using sendgrid

Tags: c#, email, azure, azure-web-app-service, sendgrid

I have created the azure sendgrid account.Actually I can be able to send the mails in azureVM with my sendgrid credentials and we published the site in azure portal. In azure webapp the same email failed to send with the error as in below :

“ Unable to read data from the transport connection:net_io_connectionclosed.” 
C# code I'm using to send mail:

At first i tried using smtp

```
var smtpSection = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");
var mail = new MailMessage();
var smtpServer = new SmtpClient(smtpSection.Network.Host);
mail.From = new MailAddress(smtpSection.Network.UserName);
mail.From = new MailAddress("john@example.com", "John Smith");
mail.To.Add(userId);
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.Body = body;
smtpServer.Port = smtpSection.Network.Port;
smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpSection.Network.UserName, smtpSection.Network.Password);
smtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
smtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Web config content:

```
<network defaultCredentials="true" host="smtp.sendgrid.net" port="25" userName="mysendgriduserid@azure.com" password="mysendgridpassword" />
```

it failed in azure webapp but works fine in azureVM. Then I tried using sendgrid api below:

```
SendGridMessage myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
myMessage.AddTo(userId);
myMessage.From = new MailAddress("john@example.com", "John Smith");
myMessage.Subject = subject;
myMessage.Text = body;
var transportWeb = new Web("myapikey");
transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
```

This also failed in azure webapp but works fine in azureVM. Both shows the same error as in image.

I'm completely clueless.Please help me to get rid of this error.

Thanks.

My apologies. I couldn't upload the image. I just share the stack trace in the image:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.]
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine) +1829453
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine) +227
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller) +16
   System.Net.Mail.CheckCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String& response) +54
   System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode) +36
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) +88
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1661

[SmtpException: Failure sending mail.]
   Dme.Application.Repositories.<Dme-Application-Repositories-IIdentityRepository-SendEmailAsync>d__22.MoveNext() +259
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +25
   Dme.Application.Services.<Dme-Shared-Contracts-IIdentityService-CreateOrUpdateUserAsync>d__14.MoveNext() +5421
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +25
   Dme.Web.UI.Areas.Admin.Controllers.<SaveOrUpdate>d__13.MoveNext() +962
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.114.0
```

Comment: Can you please provide the image you're talking about?

Comment: Did you check the the port 25 is open ?

Answer (score 1):

That's usually an error from within your own internal network. It's likely that the port you're trying to send through is closed - either by a firewall or your ISP. 
Does `telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 25` work for you ? Alternately you could try using port 465(SSL) or 587 (TLS/plain connection).

Answer (score 1):

I think you might use the API wrongly, e.g pass wrong parameters into function

i created an empty Asp.net MVC app, and able to send email via SendGrid from Azure App Service

Here is the repo: https://github.com/shrimpy/SendGridSample

And below is the code snip from https://github.com/shrimpy/SendGridSample/blob/master/SendGridSample/Controllers/EmailController.cs

```
namespace SendGridSample.Controllers
{
    public class EmailController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/SendMail")]
        public string SendMail(string email, string username, string password)
        {

            // Create the email object first, then add the properties.
            var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();

            // Add the message properties.
            myMessage.From = new MailAddress("hello@hello.com");

            // Add multiple addresses to the To field.
            List<String> recipients = new List<String> { email };

            myMessage.AddTo(recipients);

            myMessage.Subject = "Testing the SendGrid Library";

            //Add Text bodies
            myMessage.Text = "Hello World from " + Environment.MachineName;

            // Create a Web transport, using API Key
            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            var transportWeb = new Web("This string is a SendGrid API key", nc, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

            // Send the email.
            transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);

            return "done";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using the SmtpClient class, try setting your Web config to (change defaultCredentials from true to false):

```
<network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.sendgrid.net" port="25" userName="mysendgriduserid@azure.com" password="mysendgridpassword" />
```

If trying the SendGrid classes trying awaiting the DeliverAsync call

```
await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
```